# Hibernate cannot find lazy-loaded (NOPROXY) property in snapshot during PostUpdate event

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading

I'm using Hibernate 5.3.24 in Wildfly 26 with bytecode enhancement to support lazy loading ToOnes and hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true (which I know is a code smell).

I am attempting to log changes to attributes using a PostUpdateEventListener:

```
public void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event)
        throws HibernateException {

    Object entity = event.getEntity();
    String[] properties = event.getPersister().getPropertyNames();

    for (int i : event.getDirtyProperties()) {
            Object oldValue = event.getOldState()[i];
            Object newValue = event.getState()[i];
 
            if (!(newValue instanceof PersistentCollection )) {
                log.debug("property: " + properties[i] 
                  + " has changed from " + oldValue 
                  + " class: " + (oldValue == null ? "NULL" : oldValue.getClass()) 
                  + " to " + newValue 
                  + " class: " + (newValue == null ? "NULL" : newValue.getClass()));

//  Logging logic follows

            }
        }
    }
```

This works well for simple attributes and eagerly loaded ToOnes.  The problem occurs for ToOnes that are lazy loaded:

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=true)
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    public UserGroup getGroup()
    {
        return group;
    }
```

In my test case, `group` is lazy-loaded during a request (in a temporary transaction). The property is changed in a subsequent request.  In a later 'save' request, the changed entity is merged into the current PersistenceContext.  In the PostUpdate event listener, oldValue is always `org.hibernate.bytecode.enhance.spi.LazyPropertyInitializer.UNFETCHED_PROPERTY` (`<lazy>` in the logging statement).  newValue is the expected changed value.

Is there another way to find the lazy-loaded value post update?  Or in another phase?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the normal behavior. If I got it correctly, you have 2 separate transactions. You read the entity in the first one and use it in the second one, and you would like to access some lazy loaded fields in the second one. You have a few different options here:

- You access the lazy load field in the first transaction, so it will load, and you will be able to use it in the second one
- You read again the entity from the db in the second transaction
- You put all the logic in just one transaction